# Doit-on dire « de suite » ou « tout de suite » ?

Tags: expressions, usage, choix-de-mot

Pour spécifier « maintenant », j'entends parfois des personnes employer les termes « de suite » ou « tout de suite », de manière systématique.

Les deux expressions sont-elles correctes ?

Si oui, pourquoi existe-t-il cette différence alors que ces expressions signifient la même chose ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ces deux expressions sont correctes, sans être soutenues, et ont normalement des sens différents :

- **Tout de suite**

*Tout de suite* exprime l'immédiateté.

> Viens **tout de suite** ! (*Viens **immédiatement** !*)

ou encore

> En entrant dans cette chambre j'ai **tout de suite** compris qu'elle était infestée de moustiques. (*En entrant dans cette chambre j'ai **instantanément** compris qu'elle était infestée de moustiques.*)

- **De suite**

*De suite* signifie *successivement* (ou encore *d'affilée*, *à la suite les uns des autres*).

> Il a gagné trois matchs **de suite**. C'est un champion ! (*Il a gagné trois matchs **successifs**. C'est un champion !*)

Mais il arrive cependant que *de suite* soit utilisé en tant que contraction de *tout de suite*. Cette pratique est par exemple courante dans le Sud de la France :

> Si tu ne viens pas **de suite**, tu vas avoir des problèmes. (*Si tu ne viens pas **tout de suite**, tu vas avoir des problèmes.*)

Comment: Pour préciser le dernier point, _de suite_ utilisé comme contraction est plutôt familier ou régional (Sud).

Comment: Pourquoi pour spécifier _maintenant_, certains utilisent systématiquement _tout de suite_ et d'autres systématiquement _de suite_?

Comment: @Zistoloen comme je dis plus haut, dans le Sud de la France on utilisera plutôt _de suite_ mais c'est une utilisation régionale.

Comment: @FredericS: Je demande justement à Shlublu d'éditer sa réponse en incorporant ta bonne remarque.

Comment: "De suite" en tant que contraction de "tout de suite" est également utilisé à Paris, et une forme contractée est par nature moins soutenue que sa forme originale. Est-ce que ça vaut un edit, du coup ? (Si vous pensez que oui, je m'en charge)

Comment: @Shlublu: Je pense qu'un edit en rajoutant que certains (en fonction de la zone géographique) utilisent systématiquement _de suite_ au lieu de _tout de suite_ vaut le coup.

Comment: Ok, je viens d'effectuer un édit en ce sens.

Answer (score 1):

*Tout de suite*, c'est français, et, effectivement, à Marseille par exemple les gens utilisent une abréviation familière :

> J'arrive de suite !